# Make array indexes negative

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I need to change sign of numeric indexes in array.

Sample code:

```
$arr = array(0 => "test", 1 => "abc", -1 => "test");
$result = array();
var_dump($arr);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) $result[-$k] = $v;
var_dump($result);
```

But it feels that making copy of table is a bit overkill. Is there any array_* function or combination of them that will do it better than my example? If so - how to do it?

Comment: What's the use case here? Why do you need the keys to be negative integers?

Comment: @TimLewis: I've been working with very old php code from previous workers and one of "not-so-smart-design" things was that most of system depends on id's with minus sign before. I needed them back in normal way and at first it seemed it is trivial task, the more I've been digging onto it, the more it seemed like a very interesting coding problem. So now I am asking SO Community out of curiosity.

Comment: Whatever you do, the minimum is to iterate over the array once. Anything more than that is unnecessary. You can either do as you did or by reference or use an array function but the result and time it takes is about the same.

Comment: Because of your potential for duplicate keys (as your sample shows), creating a new array will always be required, too.